# python - DRF - KeyError on Date value when posting a JSON object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My problem is similar to what has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535076/keyerror-id-when-trying-to-access-request-data-in-viewset-create-definition) but with some differences. I am writing a user creation web interface with Django (ver. 2) Rest Framework (ver. 3.7) on Python 3.6, using Django's `AbstractUser` class.

My `views.py`:

```
   def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My `serializers.py` :

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    avatar = Base64ImageField()
    official_docs = Base64ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True},
                        }


    def create(self, validated_data):
        hashed_password = make_password(validated_data['password'])  # get the hashed password
        user = UserProfile(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email = validated_data['email'],
            first_name= validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name= validated_data['last_name'],
            phone_number=validated_data['phone_number'],
            avatar=validated_data.pop('avatar'),
            gender=validated_data['gender'],
            city=validated_data['city'],
            description=validated_data['description'],
            date_of_birth=validated_data.pop('date_of_birth'),
            official_docs=validated_data.pop('official_docs'),
            team_name=validated_data['team_name'],
            debit_card_number=validated_data['debit_card_number'],
            favorite_music=validated_data['favorite_music'],
        )
        user.set_password(hashed_password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Now when I post a JSON string to create user, I always have below error :

```
File "views.py" in post
  27.             serializer.save()

File ".virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "serializers.py" in create
  36.             date_of_birth=validated_data.pop('date_of_birth'),

Exception Type: KeyError at /users/
Exception Value: 'date_of_birth'
```

I have checked different sources and tried different methods to deserialize and save the JSON object but had no luck. Can someone show me where my problem is?

P.S: As requested, I've added my `models.py` :

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    "The Profile of a user with details are stored in this model."

    username = models.TextField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=50,blank=True,default='')
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length=100,blank=True,default='')
    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=11,blank=True,default='')
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='../Static/1.jpeg')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M')
    city = models.TextField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='NY')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, default='')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Config_Table, blank=True, default='')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    official_docs = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='../Static/1.jpeg')
    team_name = models.TextField(blank=True,default='')
    debit_card_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    MUSIC_CHOICES = (
        ('Rock','Rock Music'),
        ('Trad','Traditional Music'),
        ('Elec','Electronic Music'),
        ('Clas','Classical Music')
    )
    favorite_music = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True,default=''),size=2,blank=True, default='{}')
```

and a sample data :

```
  {
    "username": "12345678000",
    "password": "thisisatest",
    "last_login": null,
    "is_superuser": false,
    "email" : "h.g@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "phone_number": "12345678000",
    "gender": "M",
    "city": "NY",
    "description": "",
    "date_of_birth": "2010-03-28",
    "team_name": "",
    "avatar": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
    "official_docs": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
    "debit_card_number": 0,
    "favorite_music": [],
    "groups": [1],
    "user_permissions": [],
    "interests": ["Ski"]
}
```

Comment: Can you add UserProfile model and data you tried to post?

Comment: Please add the `UserProfile` model to the post. Also `user.set_password` expects the raw password as input, not the hashed password. Please change that in your code

Comment: OK, I will change that in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date_of_birth` removed from validated data because you added `auto_now_add=True` to this field. This tells to serializer that value will be set automatically and that it's not required to receive it from user.
To fix it just remove `auto_now_add=True` in model:

```
date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True)
```

and run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Also as  rtindru said in comment you don't need `hashed_password = make_password(validated_data['password'])` in serializer's create methos. `set_password` will make hashing for you, just use:

```
user.set_password(validated_data['password')
```